# JUnit & InterruptedException

Tags: java, junit

Изучаю Java (пока для саморазвития, а там как пойдет). В классе есть метод, который стартует генерацию возможно, большого массива. И есть метод получения этого массива. Разделил, методы для реализации генерации в отдельном потоке.

```
public float[][] getTerra() {
    if (task.isAlive()) {
        try {
            task.join(); //жду, чтобы terra сгенерилась до конца
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) { // <--- Codecov redline
            //empty
        }
    }
    return terra;
}
```

codecov (покрытие Unit-тестами) выдает, что никак не тестируется обработка `catch (InterruptedException)`. Как можно покрыть строку тестами, учитывая, что `task` - это приватный объект, и к нему не предполагается никакого доступа извне? Или я неправильно жду окончания работы потока?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам действительно следует переписать сам алгоритм получения массива, как из-за недетерминизма возвращаемого значения, так и как раз из-за того, что вы не можете его протестировать, в частности, вы можете значительно улучшить работу с генерацией массива, превратив это из отдельного потока в отдельную задачу.

Конкретно в этой ситуации вы связаны по рукам и ногам по двум причинам:

- Вы генерируете новый тред сами в своем коде
- Модель тредов предполагает любой порядок их выполнения

Поэтому пока вы либо не подменяете саму ссылку на тред перед вызовом приведенного метода, либо не засовываете в это тред бесконечную задачу, Java формально имеет право завершить компутации в треде до того, как вы попробуете вызвать `InterruptedException` на ожидающем треде.

Забегая вперед, это довольно крепко связано с т.н. чистотой функции: чистая функция возвращает детерминированный результат для каждого набора входных параметров и не имеет внешних эффектов (side effects, какое-либо изменение состояния во внешнем для функции мире). Приведенный вами метод слишком сильно завязывается на эти самые side effects, над которыми у вас нет прямой власти, и, строго говоря, формально можно протестировать только более-менее чистый функционал (потому что иначе его становится невозможно верифицировать и дорого поддерживать - если код завязывается на внешнее состояние, то тест должен неизбежно воссоздавать его перед тестом).

Конкретно в данном случае вы никак не можете управлять внешним состоянием (выполнением или невыполнением треда в нужный момент), потому что ваш код предполагает прямой вызов изменения внешнего состояния (запуск треда); в то же время, без отсылки к внешнему состоянию вы не можете протестировать ваш код. Однако если вы делегируете выполнение задачи кому-нибудь другому, то вы сможете без проблем воссоздать этот состояние в тесте. Для решения всех проблем я предлагаю воспользоваться функционалом интерфейса `ExecutorService` - это такой сервис, который позволяет регистрировать задачи для их выполнения, при этом сам интерфейс не гарантирует, где и как будут выполняться задачи - это может быть тот же поток, другой поток, другая машина, или он вовсе будет это распечатывать на бумаге и отправлять математикам на решение. В этом случае ваш код может выглядеть так:

```
public class MapContainer {

    private final ExecutorService executor;
    private volatile Future generationTask;
    private volatile float[][] map;

    public MapContainer(ExecutorService executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    public synchronized void generate() {
        if (map != null) {
            return;
        }
        generationTask = executor.submit(() -> { map = compute(); });
    }

    public float[][] get() {
        generate();
        try {
            generationTask.get();
        } catch (Exception e) { 
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Заранее предупрежу, чо код **очень** грязный и неправильный - кроме непосредствено момента с делегацией задачи. Здесь вы отправляете задачу в `ExecutorService`, который сам разберется, где ему выполнять задачу, а потом ждете ее выполнения. Теперь вы можете в коде программы использовать результат одного из методов `Executors.*`, а в тестах использовать свою собственную реализацию, которая будет возвращать `Future` следующего характера:

```
public void get() throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Таким образом, время выполнения этого метода ограничено только вызовом `.interrupt()` на выполняющем треде и выбросом соответствующего исключения, что и нужно для теста. Теперь вы можете создать тред, вызвать в нем `mapContainer.get()` и прервать сам тред, чтобы форсировать прохождение кода по указанной ветке.

**Правильно ли это все?**

На самом деле, не очень, потому что код все еще сквозит обращениями к внешнему состоянию, а предложенный вариант с Future при неаккуратном обращении будет действительно выполняться вечно, что может подвесить вам CI-сервер. Но, боюсь, я не могу предложить вариант лучше без того, чтобы пересобрать здесь вообще все целиком. Гораздо проще было бы рассматривать InterruptedException как нечто, которое препятствует нормальному выполнению программы (и пока вы не вызываете `.interrupt` для своих целей, это действительно так) - в этом случае можно и нужно пробрасывать исключение наверх, отлавливая его на верхних уровнях и завершая программу.

В любом случае надо стремиться к чистоте кода, потому что, помимо прочих вещей, это помогает предотвратить такие ситуации и вытолкнуть обработку исключительных случаев на периферию программы (вместо того, чтобы размазывать эту обработку по всем компонентам)

В качестве постскриптума: еще лучше, чем все вышеописанное, с задачей справляется `CompletableFuture`, но я решил не усложнять и без того кривой текст.

Comment: Блин, респект! Спасибо за такой ответ!